# How does floating-point arithmetic work when one is added to a big number?

Tags: c++, floating-point

If we run this code:

```
 #include <iostream>
 int main ()
 { 
     using namespace std;
     float a = 2.34E+22f;
     float b = a+1.0f;  
     cout<<"a="<<a<<endl;
     cout<<"b-a"<<b-a<<endl;
     return 0;
 }
```

Then the result will be 0, because float number has only 6 significant digits. But float number 1.0 tries to be added to 23 digit of number. So, how program realizes that there is no place for number 1, what is the algorithm?

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic - Goldberg](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: Programs don't "realise" things - they just don't have enough bits.

Comment: Does it even compile in it's current form (sans semicolons)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step by step:

IEEE-754 32-bit binary floating-point format:

```
    sign         1 bit
    significand 23 bits
    exponent     8 bits
```

I) `float a = 23400000000.f;`

Convert `23400000000.f` to `float`:

```
23,400,000,000 = 101 0111 0010 1011 1111 1010 1010 0000 00002
               = 1.01011100101011111110101010000000002 • 234.
```

But the significand can store only 23 bits after the point. So we must round:

```
  1.01011100101011111110101 010000000002 • 234
≈ 1.010111001010111111101012 • 234
```

So, after:

`float a = 23400000000.f;`

`a` is equal to 23,399,991,808.

II) `float b = a + 1;`

```
a = 101011100101011111110101000000000002.
b = 101011100101011111110101000000000012
  = 1.01011100101011111110101000000000012 • 234.
```

But, again, the significand can store only 23 binary digits after the point. So we must round:

```
  1.01011100101011111110101 000000000012 • 234
≈ 1.010111001010111111101012 • 234
```

So, after:

```
float b = a + 1;
```

`b` is equal to 23,399,991,808.

III) `float c = b - a;`

```
101011100101011111110101000000000002 - 101011100101011111110101000000000002 = 0
```

This value can be stored in a `float` without rounding.

So, after:

```
float c = b - a;
```

`с` is equal to 0.

Comment: "But mantissa can store only 23 bits after point. So we must truncate  and round:" Where is stored intermediate value 1.0101110010101111111010100000000001 * 2^34?

Comment: This is hardware specific question. Programmers can not see that. May be this is some internal temporary register. May be this is just electrical signal which is processed on a fly.

With practical point of view you can think that float point processor works as I described. Reality may be very different from my description. But the result will be the same.

Comment: Typically, real hardware works with summary information for the trailing bits. In order to do the IEEE 754 round to nearest it is enough to have the actual value of the first bit beyond what can be stored, plus a bit indicating whether there are any lower significance one bits.

Answer (score 1):

The basic principle is that the two numbers are aligned so that the decimal point is in the same place. I'm using a 10 digit number to make it a little easier to read:

```
 a = 1.234E+10f;
 b = a+1.0f;
```

When calculating a + 1.0f, the decimal points need to be lined up:

```
 1.234E+10f becomes 1234000000.0
 1.0f       becomes          1.0
            + 
            =       1234000001.0
```

But since it's float, the 1 on the right is outside the valid range, so the number stored will be `1.234000E+10`- any digits beyond that are lost, because there is just not enough digits.

[Note that if you do this on an optimizing compiler, it may still show 1.0 as a difference, because the floating point unit uses a 64- or 80-bit internal representation, so if the calculation is done without storing the intermediate results in a variable (and a decent compiler can certainly achieve that here) With 2.34E+22f it is guaranteed to not fit in a 64-bit float, and probably not in a 80-bit one either].

Comment: There is no excuse for an “optimizing” compiler to show the result as `1.0`. Such a compiler would instead be called a crappy compiler, for arbitrarily picking constant expressions at compile-time and evaluating them with semantics that differ from run-time semantics, all of this out of any control from the programmer. Non-crappy compilers define FLT_EVAL_METHOD according to their intentions and stick to the implied semantics.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Ok, so perhaps I should say "The compiler may produce code that gives the result 1.0 from this calculation, as it doesn't store the intermediate results, and 64-bit float will result in an actual 1.0 value being added in this case".

Answer (score 0):

When adding two FP numbers, they're first converted to the same exponent. In decimal:
`2.34000E+22 + 1.00000E0 = 2.34000E22 + 0.000000E+22`. In this step, the 1.0 is lost to rounding.

Binary floating point works pretty much the same, except that E+22 is replaced by 2^77.